# Probabilities for quantum random number generators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, chaos-theory, stochastic-processes, randomness

Consider a quantum random number generator (QRNG) **X**, which generates integers at random.

(Apparently, due to quantum statistical properties, this type of generation is truly at random, see e.g. ["The quantum number generator"](https://daily.jstor.org/the-quantum-random-number-generator/).)

My question is: *what is the probability that **X** generates a given integer $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?*

From the mathematical viewpoint there appears to be some obstruction, in that uniform distributions on a countable set do not exist: if $p > 0$ would be the positive probability assigned to each integer, then $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}p = \infty$, and not $1$.

On the other hand, it might be that $p$ simply should be taken $0$, and that the classical idea of uniform probability is not relevant in this quantum-mechanical context ?

But if it is, then random generation does not imply that integers are chosen with the same probability, which seems a very interesting feature to me ...

Answer (score 2):

The quantum random number generator described in the article does *not* generate a random integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It generates a random *bit* $b \in \{0,1\}$. Although you could (in theory) use any finite number $k$ of these bit generators to generate a random integer in the range $[0,2^k-1]$, this is not the same as generating a random integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Any physical random number generator that claims to generate a random integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with a uniform distribution is clearly bogus because it will almost certainly generate a number that requires more bits than the number of fundamental particles in the observable universe to represent it.